# plantuml : strange behavior when including multiple times startsub parts

Tags: plantuml

Taking this small example to illustrate my problem.

**common.puml**

```
@startuml common

!startsub COMMON

abstract Common {
    id : uuid
}

!endsub

@enduml
```

**myclass1.puml**

```
@startuml myclass1

!includesub common.puml!COMMON

class MyClass1 extends Common {
    text: string
}

@enduml
```

**myclass2.puml**

```
@startuml myclass1

!includesub common.puml!COMMON

class MyClass2 extends Common {
    value: int
}

@enduml
```

**all.puml**

```
@startuml all

!include ./sub/common.puml
!include ./sub/myclass1.puml
!include ./sub/myclass2.puml

@enduml
```

When redering the **all.puml** diagram, I have a strange result in the Common part.
Attributes are rendered 3 times !

Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Note: your imageand the code does not correspond, I think you did a wrong cut / paste for myclass2.puml

Comment: I don't know the rationale behind the `!includesub` is but excluding them from myclass1 / myclass2 solves the issue

Comment: I use !includesub to add some objects that are in other files.
If I don't use the !includesub, I can not renderer the myclass1.puml and myclass2.puml independently (I will only have the Common object but without attributes).

Is there a possibility to test if an object is already present ?

Such like this :

if not exists(COMMON )
   !includesub common.puml!COMMON
endif

Comment: I don't know whether this exists, but as you also made an issue at https://forum.plantuml.net/11922/strange-behavior-including-multiple-times-startsub-parts I suggest that you this question / my remarks from the comments to your question there as well.

Comment: What to you meen by "excluding them from" ?

Comment: Remove the line or comment the line from `myclass1.puml` and `myclass2.puml`, but seen your first comment I think this won't be a good solution for you.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76133309/1168342

Answer (score 0):

It's either a feature or a bug. Include files just put the code from the file inside another. Since `common.puml` ends up being included three times (once in `all`, once in `myclass1`, and once in `myclass2`), you wind up more or less with:

```
abstract Common {
    id : uuid
}

abstract Common {
    id : uuid
}

abstract Common {
    id : uuid
}
```

which will produce

[image]

Maybe you can prevent this from happening by defining a variable, e.g., `!$common = 1` inside the part of `common.puml` that you don't want to repeat, and check before doing the `!includesub`, e.g.

```
...
!if (%not($common == 1))
!includesub common.puml!COMMON
!endif
...
```

(Note - I didn't test this!)